# desktop application with NW.js and php

Tags: php, node.js

I need to create a stand alone local window app using web front-end code and PHP.
Noticing that good old TideSDK is completely dead I tried searching around and the only viable option seems to be NW.js and his extension "baconface php-webkit" (https://github.com/baconface/php-webkit). Fact is, I cant even manage to start!
1- I download NW.js for windows and extract the files in a new desktop folder
2- I open a node.js console and execute these commands (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)
3- I paste php-webkit files into the folder overwriting package.json
4- try to exec NW.exe and just get the message that Express is not present

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your step 2, and 3. Copy the files into that folder then from there just run a npm install to get all needed dependencies.

I followed your steps except reversing, and it worked for me! Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer!
I did as you told and now I don't get the error anymore, but it doesn't start by loading application/index.php
do you maybe know how to solve also this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey, I am the author of this. I admit the code is rough and needs a rewrite but I haven't had time to. It should still work. If not the screen should turn red and the loading message should now be an error message. Do you get this and what does it say? Common reasons for this is you have either not packaged PHP with it, don't have PHP installed at all, or it might be a permission issue accessing PHP which might or might not be fixed with the PR I haven't looked at yet. - https://github.com/baconface/php-webkit/pull/19

Comment: And if you get just the NW.js splash screen. Then the php-webkit wasn't loaded at all. And it could be an issue with you packaging/running NW.js.